# The list cannot be displayed in DataSheet view

Tags: 2010, datasheet

I have two SharePoint Enterprise 2010 sites in two different farms. Both sites I am accessing with my local browser IE 10 (32-bit). List1 in Site1 can be opened in DataSheet view but List2 in Site2 cannot be opened in DataSheet view. I have 64-bit Office 2013 installed. I am using 64-bit Office but still can open List1 of Site1 in DataSheet view but cannot open List2 in Site2 in DataSheet view which is in another farm. This is quite strange! Any advice and suggestions what is wrong or missing?

Here is the common exception I encounter while opening List2 of Site2 in DataSheet view:

The list cannot be displayed in DataSheet view for one or more of the following reasons:

- A datasheet component compatible with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation is not installed.
- Your web browser does not support ActiveX controls.
- A component is not properly configured for 32-bit or 64-bit support.

Comment: Have you set up excel services in both farms? Check that excel calculation service is started and that the excel service application is created.

Comment: This thread might help you to: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/80e994b9-86c5-44a1-b83c-6ef9299168d8/a-datasheet-component-compatible-with-microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-2010-is-not-installed-error?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: Check that both sites are connecting using the same security level in IE.  To do this open the working list, go to Internet options in IE and select the Security tab.  I suspect this site will be Local Intranet or Trusted sites.  Do the same for the site that doesn't work, I suspect you'll find its Internet.  If it is try adding the site to the same security level as the one that works (Though you may find the option to do so is locked down as some companies have policies to prevent users changing these settings).

Comment: PS Datasheet has nothing to do with Excel Services.  Its controlled by a DLL that's supplied with Microsoft Office.  If your running 64-bit Office then normally the datasheet view doesn't work but if you also have some office 32 bit stuff installed (or commonly people install the Access 2007 Runtime) then it will.  In your case you must have the right DLL installed as otherwise it wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 3):

Instaling of "2007 Office System Driver: Data Connectivity Components" resolved issue for me.
Here is the link - 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue myself and was able to resolve it by performing the following steps:

- Close any and all open Excel windows.
- Open a new browser process (For IE, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd>, then <kbd>I</kbd>).
- Navigate to the same list and attempt to access datasheet view again.

Apparently, in my case, the issue was related to something in memory from one of my running Excel processes.

Answer (score 0):

I get this same issue from time to time, restarting my computer resolves it for me for months at a time. Not permanent solution, but worth a try while your looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:
Data Connectivity Components 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your Microsoft office to 32 bit from 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

I have windows 10 with Microsoft Edge.

My solution is as follow:
Open the Microsoft Edge, & then Settings - More tools & Open with Internet Explorer

that's it, now the datasheet is working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

1. Open regular Internet Explorer, not Edge.
2. Make sure the menu bar is visible. Select Tools --> Compatibility and add your list to the sites that should open in compatibility view.
3. It should reload into datasheet view.

Answer (score -1):

If the Datasheet is not grayed out, but you cannot select it for IE11:
- Go to Tools -> Select Enterprise Mode